# Add tag for ONLYOFFICE

Tags: support, tags

I want to suggest adding the [onlyoffice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onlyoffice) tag on Stack Overflow. I cannot add it myself, because I have less than 1500 reputation points.

According to [this help entry](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support):

> Stack Overflow can help support your product but it can't be the only support

And there is already [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE) support, and [dev forum](http://dev.onlyoffice.org/) for this product, but since some people ask questions about their problems on Stack Overflow, and since there are already [several questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=onlyoffice+is%3Aq) for this product, the tag can be useful.

Description:

- ONLYOFFICE is an open source office web-suite.
- It includes online document editors, projects, CRM, calendar,
  community with forums and blogs, and mail server.
- It can be used as a free alternative to Google Docs, deployed on your own server.

Comment: are the questions related to onlyoffice on topic for stackoverflow?

Comment: @daniel-a-white I think some questions, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33452367/online-document-editing-in-j2ee-based-web-applications-with-onlyoffice-but-call) are programming related, but agree some question are better in Server Fault

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have created the [onlyoffice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onlyoffice) tag (note that tag names have to be lowercase). Keep in mind that some questions, e.g. about setting up an OnlyOffice server, might be off-topic on Stack Overflow; [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) might be a better place for those questions, but be sure to read their [help center](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) before posting such a question.

Comment: To be honest, I don't think this tag should have been created.

Comment: @Ajeets: Because someone went back and [retagged them](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38412452/3)?

Comment: If the [tag:onlyoffice] is created today, why do I see total **3** [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onlyoffice) and the oldest one was asked on `Mar 13, 2015 at 16:53`?

Comment: @mark-rotteveel onlyoffice have a pretty complex [API](https://api.onlyoffice.com), so separate StackOverflow tag can help some users to figure it out.